# HC-05 Bluetooth module on breakout board with straight header pins

Tags: bluetooth, pins, hc-05

Has anyone found the HC-05 bluetooth module (on the breakout board) with straight header pins?  I seem to only be able to find them with the 90 degree header pins.  Removing those and soldering on straight ones for my project is getting tiresome...  I would even be happy to find them without header pins (but still on the breakout board).

Comment: In short: no. How many do you need that it's becoming tiresome? If the quantity is that high it's worth designing a custom PCB to take the module directly.

Comment: That is what I thought :-\  Thanks Majenko.  I will move forward with redesign to integrate just the module.

Comment: please post a link to the module or a picture of the module